# Двоеточие в бессоюзном предложении в значении "а именно"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, двоеточие, бессоюзное

Скажите, пожалуйста, здесь можно поставить двоеточие?

> И я думаю об одном деле, которое я не закончил(:) где-то здесь должна
> быть маленькая девочка, страдающая в руках психопата.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие уместно, если по смыслу его можно заменить на "а именно", см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/).

> В бессоюзном сложном предложении между частями ставится двоеточие, «если вторая часть бессоюзного предложения поясняет то, о чем говорится в первой части; в таких случаях возможна подстановка слов *а именно*: *Весна, конечно, движется: в пруду, еще не совсем растаявшем, лягушки высунулись, урчат вполголоса* (Пришв.); *И от этих ее слов всем хорошо становилось, спокойно, как в детстве: тихо светит солнце, тихо скользят времена года…* (Т. Толст.).

> В первой части бессоюзного сложного предложения могут быть слова, предупреждающие о последующем пояснении: *Проходит еще сколько-то времени, а тут новая **неуправка**: захворал дедушка, некому пахать и сеять* (Пришв.); *Тогда произошло на даче **событие**, похожее на чудо: куст шиповника, угнетенный, вышел на свет и зацвел в сентябре, и цвел до морозов* (Пришв.); *Дни мои всё более переливаются в память. И жизнь превращается в нечто странное, **двойное**: есть одна, всамделишняя, и другая, призрачная, изделие памяти, и они существуют рядом* (Триф.). <...>

**ВЫВОД**

В вашем случае двоеточие уместно:

*И я думаю об одном деле, которое я не закончил: где-то здесь должна быть маленькая девочка, страдающая в руках психопата.*